# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.(IIS Server)

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, iis-10

I am getting this error - 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
when i am trying to access website just using webistename.com. If i manually type https:// before it works. It also works if i refresh. I tried deleting browser cache memory(history). It dint solve the issue, also since i am using IIS 10 server i don't have a .htaccess file.

How can I solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: could you please share your bindings of the iis site and have you purchased the domain name? and what is the sub status code in the iis logs? make sure you have configured the default document for the site in iis

Comment: The domain name is purchased. Bindings are the following. I uploaded bindings screen shot here https://easyupload.io/eodamd  .This are the default document settings https://easyupload.io/gm2p51 .

Comment: what is the sub status code of the error

Comment: Here is the log file: https://easyupload.io/nuo2gh i dont know the pat for sub log files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a centOS 7 server running Plesk. I had to disable the Plesk Web Application Firewall. Nothing else worked. The server is already behind a securri firewall at GoDaddy so it seems the Plesk web app firewall is redundant. This fixed my 403 error. It was on one php file out of hundreds (most backend php processing programs) for the website

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 403.4 error only for the http url.
to suggest you to disable the require ssl setting for the website in iis by following below steps:

- Open IIS Manager
- Click on your website
- Click on the "SSL Settings" in the "IIS" section
- Uncheck "Require SSL"